# GROUP BY not work when I set foreign key relation in non-unique column

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, rdbms

Suppose I've got two tables

```
TABLE A
id     name
1      emon
2      sumon
3      mamun
4      bonna
5      ferdousi

TABLE B
id     name_id score
1      1       100
2      2       0
3      2       10
4      3       50
5      3       60
```

I want this DATA

```
name    score
emon    100
sumon   0
sumon   10
mamun   50
mamun   60
```

I know this is easy query, just like:

```
SELECT A.name, B.score FROM A 
RIGHT JOIN B
ON A.id=B.name_id
```

but this query not work when I set foreign key

```
SELECT sum(B.score) FROM A 
RIGHT JOIN B
ON A.id=B.name_id
group by B.name_id
```

My question is how can I set foreign key in this situation? I know in relational database, without relation may be not good decision. In this situation `GROUP BY` clause not work when i set foreign key. Any good idea?

Comment: That's quite a big change in the question.  You say that the 'GROUP BY clause does not work when I create a foreign key', but you don't explain what you mean.  In what way does it not work?  Does the query fail to compile, or does it produce unexpected results?  What result does it produce?  What were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to the revised question

Paraphrasing the question:

> Why does this query not work against the schema?
>
> ```
> SELECT sum(B.score) FROM A 
> RIGHT JOIN B
> ON A.id=B.name_id
> GROUP BY B.name_id
> ```

Part of the answer must be "in what way does it 'not work'?"  As written, the query should produce an answer row for every row in B.

```
100
 10
110
```

The RIGHT OUTER JOIN (ROJ) really doesn't make any difference to the query result; you could as well have omitted the keyword RIGHT and would get the same result:

```
SELECT SUM(B.score)
  FROM A 
  JOIN B ON A.id = B.name_id
 GROUP BY B.name_id
```

If, as seems plausible, you want the name and aggregate score for each player listed in table A, then you'd write:

```
SELECT A.Name, SUM(B.Score) AS TotalScore
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.Name_ID
 GROUP BY A.Name
```

The RIGHT OUTER JOIN has been replaced by a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  This will list all the players.

#### Answer to the original version of the question

The original question applied to the schema shown and asked:

> My question is how can I set a foreign key in this situation?

1. You will have a primary key on TableA(ID).
2. You will have a primary key on TableB(ID).
3. You will create a foreign key on TableB(Name_ID) that references TableA(ID).

Comment: when I create foreign key `GROUP BY` clause not work for B.name_id

Comment: I find that difficult to believe.  What is your evidence for that claim?  In what way does it not work?

Comment: thank you very much. It solved. and also sorry for my week expression

Answer (score 1):

You would set a foreign key on `B.name_id` referencing `A.id`.

In MySQL this would be done like:

```
ALTER TABLE B ADD FOREIGN KEY (name_id) REFERENCES A(id)
```

*Note: If you do not already have an index on `name_id`, you should create this first.*

In this situation `A.id` is the column that has to be unique. I'm guessing it is already the primary key of table A though so this is not a problem.

The benefit of having a foreign key is it maintains referential integrity. That is, you are guaranteed that every `name_id` in B actually refers to an existing record in A. Without a foreign key, you would be able to insert the row `name_id=999, score=50` in B, which refers to nobody. With a foreign key, the database engine will reject this insert.

Comment: the problem is suppose I set foreign in name_id in B to id in A. but there a problem when i want to know total score in a name_id. I mean when I use `GROUP BY` for a name_id it cant execute because each column has set foreign key. r u clear?

Comment: @coder I'm not following. What is your query with `GROUP BY` that does not work?